# Not getting values after decimal in selectbox price

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

as you can see in the code below there are some values after the decimal point in the price attribute `price="20.77"`. The jquery function is working perfectly however its not bringing over the cents. I have no clue why and i cant find the solution anywhere else.

All help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".cart66-select").change(function(){
            var price = parseInt(jQuery(this).find(':selected').attr('price')).toFixed(2);
            jQuery("#price").html(price);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="cart66-select">
    <option value="1" price="10.99">Coral</option>
    <option value="2" price="20.77">Passion Fruit (+5.00)</option>
</select>
<strong class="cart66-price-value">$<span id="price">24.22</span></strong>
```

Comment: `parseInt` is getting only the integer part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `parseFloat()` instead.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".cart66-select").change(function(){
            var price = parseFloat(jQuery(this).find(':selected').attr('price')).toFixed(2);
            jQuery("#price").html(price);
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this (or any answer) has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, but besides the reputation you will help future readers to find the answer they have been looking for. @Xirlas